# How do I add to a byte arraylist?

Tags: java

```
private ArrayList<byte[]> patterns = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
```

I want to add these arrays to an ArrayList:

```
byte[] array1 = new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43 };

byte[] array1 = new byte[] { 0x58, 0x59, 0x5A };
```

The end game is so that I can have a function iterate through the ArrayList and swap the contents of this array out with it:

```
private byte[] bytes;
```

How would something like this be possible?

For example,

```
public void changePattern(){
//code to change pattern

private byte[] bytes;
/*It adds array1 to this above and once finished 
cycles through to array2 and keeps going if there are more arrays.*/
}
```

Comment: `patterns.add(array1)` ?

Comment: @Michael I tried that it doesn't work.  `patterns.add(array1);`

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Here is [a runnable example](https://ideone.com/T6RybB) contradicting you.

Comment: So I copy and pasted your code and get this error on the patterns.add(array1) line. https://imgur.com/a/0uYkNfy

Comment: Imgur is banned on my network. Use words.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line -Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to come QualifiedName -Syntax error, insert "Identifer ("to complete MethodHeaderName) -Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token.-Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethoDeclaration.

Comment: @Michael I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment, so this can be resolved.

Comment: I created a new class and it still has the same error.

Comment: Could you show the full class what do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    byte[] array1 = new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43 };
    byte[] array2 = new byte[] { 0x58, 0x59, 0x5A };
    byte [] joinedArray = join(array1, array2);
    for (byte b : joinedArray) {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}

private static byte[] join(byte[] a, byte[] b) {
    byte[] c = new byte[a.length + b.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, c, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, c, a.length, b.length);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
byte[] array1 = new byte[] { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43 };
byte[] array1 = new byte[] { 0x58, 0x59, 0x5A };

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
outputStream.write( array1 );
outputStream.write( array1 );

byte bytes[] = outputStream.toByteArray( );
```